# Tensorflow Installation failed. TensorContractionThreadPool.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, eigen

I try to install Tensorflow from source.

```
./configure
bazel build --copt=-march=native --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

but when I do 'bazel build ...' it raise an Exception like this..

```
ERROR: /home/anderson/Downloads/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:300:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:reader_base' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fPIE -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter ... (remaining 115 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_types.h:25:0,
             from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:23,
             from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:22,
             from ./tensorflow/core/framework/queue_interface.h:22,
             from ./tensorflow/core/kernels/reader_base.h:21,
             from tensorflow/core/kernels/reader_base.cc:16:
./third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/FixedPoint:42:52: fatal error: src/Tensor/TensorContractionThreadPool.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

To put it simple it says **"src/Tensor/TensorContractionThreadPool.h: No such file or directory"**

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, known issue at HEAD. There's a work-around in comments of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6558

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks. but none of the suggestions do not solve the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

1. Cloned https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen
2. Copied the `Tensor` folder into tensorflow: `cp -r eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/`
3. Edit `tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/BUILD` by changing:

   ```
   glob(["unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/FixedPoint/*.h"]) + [
   ```

   into:

   ```
   hdrs = glob(["unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/FixedPoint/*.h"]) +
          glob(["unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/*.h"]) + [
   ```

   You could probably also use `.../src/*/*.h`
4. Run `bazel build` as normal

Answer (score 0):

@naktinis is right!
but hg clone repo from bitbucket is bother，u should install Mercurial first by:

```
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ apt-get install mercurial

# Fedora
$ yum install mercurial

# Gentoo
$ emerge mercurial

# Mac OS (homebrew)
$ brew install mercurial

# FreeBSD
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/mercurial
$ make install

# Solaris 11 Express
$ pkg install SUNWmercurial
```